# input class object into array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a program that takes a string and an integer in a class object. The program will then sort the class objects, in an array of objects, by the integer, allowing me to then display the names. Unfortunately, when I try to build the array, I have an error on my assignment operator.

My questions are: Do I need to overload the `=` operator, and if so, how (somehow I've never figured out how to overload operators)? If not, where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    void InitiativeList::makeList(size_type physicalSize, size_type logicalSize)
    {
        string sNewActor;
        int iNewOrder;
        for (size_t index = 0; index < physicalSize; index++)
        {
            if (logicalSize == physicalSize)
            {
                grow(physicalSize);
            }
            cout << "Enter character name: ";
            cin >> sNewActor;

            if (sNewActor == "Exit")
            {
                return;
            }

            cout << "Enter initiative roll: ";
            cin >> iNewOrder;
            actorOrder[index] = new Actor(iNewOrder, sNewActor);
            logicalSize++;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "_but I figure it's better to show everything_" - NO it is not.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And unless you're asking about build errors, then make sure the example actually builds. And *if* you're asking about build errors (which I think you are) then copy (as text) the full and complete build output and paste it into the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `new` there, because you have an array of `actorData` and not `actorData` pointers, and the error is saying that it can't convert `actorData` pointer to `actorData`. So replace this line:

```
actorOrder[index] = new actorData(iNewOrder, sNewActor);
```

with this:

```
actorOrder[index] = actorData(iNewOrder, sNewActor);
```